# Responsive design to intermix to columns of content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been searching for an extensible way to take 2 columns of content from a webpage and responsively collapse this to 1 column in an extensible manner.  The issue is very neatly stated [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/25/maintain-hierarchy-content-choreography/) in pictures, and referred to as the intermixing content problem.

This article is about a year old now, and I was wondering if there has been progress made towards a cross-browser framework or coding practice that addresses this specific issue.

For context, I have two columns of content, originally separated by category and each column ordered by date.  I want this to collapse to 1 column when appropriate, and all content of that column to be ordered by date.

Links to tutorials, articles or other resources welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the 3 columns in your responsive sample website fold to 2 columns but not down to 1 column. Technically, those columns do not fold, they skip a row down as screen width gets narrower. At only ONE column, the column width expands to 100%.   I make it less than 100% so there is a border allowance for aesthetic reasons.  Use "@media" methods for various device widths.

Keep in mind, I do not use 100% as full width, because in responsive design if you put a border to your column, even a 1px border width will pop out the horizontal scroll bar.

The following columns go to full width at a smartphone-sized screens of less than 480px:

Example

.column1of1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.column1of2 {
  width: 48%;
}

.column1of3 {
  width: 31%;
}

@media only screen and (max width: 480px) {

.column1of1, .column1of2, column1of3 {
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  font-size: 80%;

}
}

I hope the above helps.  I don't think I understood what you are planning with the dates.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I didn't mean that webpage itself but the content of the article.  They talk about having several boxes inside two separate columns, and when we collapse down to one column the all of these boxes combine in a nontrivial way (i.e. they kinda splice together, in my case based on some criteria of the content of these boxes), instead of some geometric pattern.  So in my two columns I have several boxes.  Say the collection of boxes are separated into two columns by color originally, and each box contains a date.  I want to mash them into one column ordered chronologically

Comment: It can be done without the help of javascript, however, it has its limitations. Some of the columns will need height value.  Depending on the content, column heights can create aesthetic problems such as too much padding at the bottom.  I prepared an example [link]**http://jsfiddle.net/KK838/2/**   It will need fine-tuning, of course.  You will be able to evaluate better in a browser.

Comment: Excellent example.  Thanks.  So is it correct to say that the current best practice for ordering these boxes would be the order they are entered in the DOM?  i.e. if, for example, I want to create a button that would sort these boxes by some third criteria, my best option might be to pull these boxes out of the DOM and replace them in this new sorting order?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you have in mind of how the button will look like with some third criteria, but it sounds right what you are saying.  I have been working with this structure for a year now.  It took me a while to figure how to align things.   Thank you for your point.

Comment: Nothing particular in mind at the moment, but just thinking towards extensibility.  I suppose practice goes a long way for this type of styling, and I'm just looking for current best practices before I get my hands too deep in the muck.  Nothing is harder than unlearning something when you've taught yourself how to do it the wrong way first.

Comment: Well... I would not call it the wrong way.  Let's say, this is the new way.  I grabbed the idea as soon as I discovered a month into the finding, thanks to Mr. Unstoppable Robot Ninja -- Ethan Marcotte and some others.  Good luck and have fun with responsive. I sure like it for its versatility.